# RxAndroidBle connection timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I am connecting to a discovered device and reading RSSI periodically. I need to know exactly when the connection is lost. Is there any way to specify connection timeout after which I will receive `RxBleConnectionState.DISCONNECTED`? Now I'm still receiving rssi from `rxBleConnection.readRssi()` even if connected device was powered off.

Should I use Link Loss service from Proximity Bluetooth profile instead of connection timeout?

My code:

```
device1ConnectionSubscription = device.establishConnection(false)
        .doOnUnsubscribe(this::clearDevice1Subscription)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection ->
                Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .flatMap(sequence -> rxBleConnection.readRssi())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        )
        .subscribe(this::updateDevice1Rssi, this::onConnectionFailure);


device1ConnectionStateChangesSubscription = device.observeConnectionStateChanges()
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> device1ConnectionStateChangesSubscription = null)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            connectionState -> {
                switch(connectionState)
                {
                    case DISCONNECTING:
                    case DISCONNECTED:
                        if(device1ConnectionSubscription != null) {
                            device1ConnectionSubscription.unsubscribe();
                        }
                        device1ConnectionStateChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
                        break;
                }
            },
            throwable -> { }
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you are looking for is `Connection supervision timeout`. This parameter is controlled by the device and I suppose, cannot be set on your phone.

Comment: So, is there any way to detect connection loss (host power off) in reasonable time? I can detect signal loss caused by increasing distance, but I need to know if connected device is still working.

Comment: By lowering the connection supervision timeout you can decrease the time, but it is up to the device vendor, not the client.

Comment: There is an article on `classycode` blog with a story about [`Connection Supervision Timeout`](https://blog.classycode.com/a-short-story-about-android-ble-connection-timeouts-and-gatt-internal-errors-fa89e3f6a456). TL;DR- on Android it is hardcoded to 20 seconds.

Comment: Me and out company is doing research about exactly this and what Dariusz Seweryn says in the previous comment is what we also noticed. It seems that there is no solution for this.